# if exists alter table statement with not null or default value doesn't work

Tags: sap-ase, alter-table

I try to add one new column ***column2*** into the **test_tbl** and set the column with default value ***'N/A'*** and ***not null***. The statement is following:

```
if not exists (select 1 from syscolumns where object_name(id) = 'test_tbl' and name = 'column2')
begin
  alter table test_tbl add column2 varchar(20) default 'N/A' not null
end
```

The error is

```
Could not execute statement.
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'column2' in table 'test_tbl' is specified more than once.
Sybase error code=2705
Severity Level=16, State=3, Transaction State=1
Line 4
```

But if I add one column which is ***nullable***.

```
if not exists (select 1 from syscolumns where object_name(id) = 'test_tbl' and name = 'column2')
begin
    alter table test_tbl add column2 varchar(20) null
end
```

It could work. I'm so comfused with these. 
I searched for some tags and know that the dynamic sql could work.

> The error is being raised during normalizations (as the parse tree is
>   being converted into a normalized query tree) rather than at
>   execution. The contents of dynamic sql aren't processed until they are
>   actually called, avoiding the error.

In Sybase DOC about if...else

> When an alter table, create table, or create view command occurs
>   within an if...else block, Adaptive Server creates the schema for the
>   table or view before determining whether the condition is true. This
>   may lead to errors if the table or view already exists.

I want to know why the nullable column statement could execute without error!

Answer (score 5):

I see the same behaviour on Sybase ASE 15

I can't provide you with an explanation beyond what you have already quoted from the Sybase Documentaiton, however you can script a consistent behaviour by wrapping the call to alter table in an execute() statement as follows

```
if not exists (select 1 from syscolumns where object_name(id) = 'tbl_test' and name = 'column2')
begin     
    execute("
        alter table tbl_test add column2 varchar(20) default 'N/A' not null
    ")
end
```

My guess is that the server is able to evaluate the `if...else` statement in this instance before executing the alter statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `go..`

Please check below code it's working fine for me

```
IF  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'a_table' AND type = 'U' )
drop table a_table
go
CREATE TABLE a_table ( col1 int not null,col2 int null )
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Brad's answer didn't work for me on this version:

Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP03 PL05/EBF 28236 SMP/P/AMD64/Windows 2008 R2 SP1/ase160sp03pl05x/0/64-bit/FBO/Mon Jul 30 02:37:39 2018

(I think it returned 1 if the column had ever existed on the table in the past)

This code worked:

```
if not exists (select 1 from syscolumns where id = object_id('tbl_test') and name = 'column2')
begin     
    execute("
        alter table tbl_test add column2 varchar(20) default 'N/A' not null
    ")
end
```